# boundaries target-mouse walking pygame

Tags: python, pygame, mouseevent

I have to move the player with the mouse. I'll explain better:
When I click into the screen , I have a target and my hero moves from his actual position to the new one.
I have to put the boundaries , and I'm having some problems.
I tried the solution that I'm posting here, but when the player hits the boundaries he gets stuck to these boundaries.

Hero(player) class:

```
    def get_direction(self, target):
    '''
    Function:
        takes total distance from sprite.center
        to the sprites target
        (gets direction to move)
    Returns:
        a normalized vector
    Parameters:
        - self
        - target
            x,y coordinates of the sprites target
            can be any x,y coorinate pair in
            brackets [x,y]
            or parentheses (x,y)
    '''
    if self.target: # if the square has a target
        position = Vector(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery) # create a vector from center x,y value
        target = Vector(target[0], target[1]) # and one from the target x,y
        self.dist = target - position # get total distance between target and position
        direction = self.dist.normalize() # normalize so its constant in all directions
        return direction 

def distance_check(self, dist):
    '''
    Function:
        tests if the total distance from the
        sprite to the target is smaller than the
        ammount of distance that would be normal
        for the sprite to travel
       (this lets the sprite know if it needs
        to slow down. we want it to slow
        down before it gets to it's target)
    Returns:
        bool
    Parameters:
        - self
        - dist
            this is the total distance from the
            sprite to the target
            can be any x,y value pair in
            brackets [x,y]
            or parentheses (x,y)
    '''
    dist_x = dist[0] ** 2 # gets absolute value of the x distance
    dist_y = dist[1] ** 2 # gets absolute value of the y distance
    t_dist = dist_x + dist_y # gets total absolute value distance
    speed = self.speed ** 2 # gets aboslute value of the speed
    if t_dist < (speed): # read function description above
        return True

def Walking(self):
    '''
    Function:
        gets direction to move then applies
        the distance to the sprite.center
        ()
    Parameters:
        - self
    '''
    self.dir = self.get_direction(self.target) # get direction
    if self.dir: # if there is a direction to move            
        if self.distance_check(self.dist): # if we need to stop
            self.rect.center = self.target # center the sprite on the target    
        else: # if we need to move normal    
            self.x += (self.dir[0] * self.speed) # calculate speed from direction to move and speed constant
            self.y += (self.dir[1] * self.speed)
            self.rect.center = (round(self.x),round(self.y)) # apply values to sprite.center
```

Level 1:

```
def ProcessInput(self, events):
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.__myHero.moveLeft()
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.__myHero.moveRight()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            self.__myHero.target = event.pos
            #if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                #print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
                #self.__myHero.target = pygame.mouse.get_pos() # set the sprite.target to the mouse click position



def Update(self):
    #Put your game logic in here for the scene.
    #self.SwitchToScene(SecondScene())
    if self.__myHero.x >= 740:
        self.__myHero.target = None
    else:
        self.__myHero.Walking()


def Render(self, display_game):
    display_game.blit(self.image_background, (0, 0))
    display_game.blit(self.__myHero.getImage(), self.__myHero.rect.topleft)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Main:

```
if not quit_attempt:
    active_scene.ProcessInput(filtered_events)
    active_scene.Update()
    active_scene.Render(display_game)        
    active_scene = active_scene.next
```

In the `Update()` function I used the following code:

```
if self.__myHero.x >= 740:
    self.__myHero.target = None
```

If my hero go over the boundaries , I change his target and I set it to `None`
because I want that he stops his walking. He stops himself , but remains completely blocked. I don't know why.
Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hero goes over the boundaries, you change it's target to None to stop walking. The problem here lies in the if statement that performs this action.
Once you enter this statment:

```
if self.__myHero.x >= 740:
    self.__myHero.target = None
```

The value of `self.__myHero.x` remains bigger or equal to 740. Therefore you should do something to avoid that the value of `self.__myHero.x` is bigger or equal to 740 within the if statement otherwise you will keep setting `None` into `self.__myHero.target`

Comment: Perfect my friend! you help me a lot :)